# Toddlers never remove/change "Nintendo Game Card" properly, are there any possible risks to the hardware?

Tags: nintendo-switch, physical-media

The toddlers constantly generate this error because they don't exit the game cleanly when they remove the Nintendo Game Card.

> Software closed because game card was removed

In German the error is

> Die Software wurde beendet weil die Softwarekarte entfernt wurde.

I believe this error message can be ignored since the Nintendo Game Card are read only media. Or am I wrong, are there risks to my hardware and/or games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game card itself won't be damaged in any way since, like you said, the data is read only. The only thing to really be wary of is if the game is in the middle of saving or has some sort of auto save function. Removing the game card during saving data could potentially corrupt that save data.

Comment: Save data is stored on the console's storage, not on the cartridge.

Comment: @rctgamer3 yes, but save data can still be potentially corrupted if it is interrupted, no matter where it's saving to.